# Is there a research about effectiveness of swipe interfaces vs tap interfaces?

Tags: mobile-application, swipe

Basically what I want to learn is how popular or useful is the swipe in comparison to the tap button in Tinder? Which one do users prefer? Are there any numbers or data about this topic?

I read some stuff but they did not answer my question: 
http://www.quora.com/Which-mobile-interface-has-a-better-UX-Tinder-swipe-left-right-or-Hot-or-Not-tap-buttons
http://www.quora.com/Are-Tinder-Jelly-and-other-finger-swipe-interfaces-the-future-of-mobile-application-design

Comment: There are quite a few relevant hits if you search for *swipe tap touch* on [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&q=swipe+tap+touch&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=).

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a few products that came to such discussions and the consensus ( not an official metrics study ) was always a swipe. The very gesture of a swipe mimics your like/dislike of whatever you are selecting/choosing. Instinctively it is more satisfying to swipe. However depending on what product you are building a tap might just do the job. I think also if you do not address such subtle way of navigation at launch of the app then the user might get confused. But by now I think it has become a rather known way of navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this study :

> **Tap, Swipe, or Move: Attentional Demands for Distracted Smartphone Input**

The conclusion is probably the most relevant part.

> "In this paper, we analyze the relative cognitive cost of motion
>   gestures, tap and surface gestures as input for smartphone devices
>   under conditions of light distraction. We show that, for both
>   walking and eyes-free input, the cognitive cost of motion gestures
>   (measured as a function of reaction time) is statistically
>   indistinguishable from the cognitive costs of taps and gestures. As
>   a result, motion gestures represent a viable input alternative for
>   situations where eyes-free input may be required. "
>
> http://yangl.org/pdf/avi12.pdf

Comment: Welcome, StackExchange doesn't like answers that are pure links. Please provide the key points from the article in your answer too

Comment: I would like to second Esq. If you can please quote the relevant parts from the article.

Comment: Hi,Alright, so sorry about that. I haven't read the whole article but this one looked relative to this problem. Will take care of that on future answers.